# Remote access of django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django 1.5 project using django models over mysql running on apache server.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthdate = models.DateField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I also have a python/django application (using django custom commands) running on a remote computer that must use these models.

- Remote application shares the same model definitions with server
- Remote application needs read only access to models
- Remote application cannot have a full dump of server database, as server must return a queryset based on user rights
- Remote application can only connect over http to server
- Server can expose the models over REST API (json)

Is there any automated way to transfer models over http? I have tried to use django.core.serializers but I had the following issues:

- I cannot serialize the related objects in a queryset
- Remote application cannot work without local database
- Remote application searches related objects on local db after deserialization (that does not exist)

Edit:

I managed to serialize models like this:

```
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('author').all()
authors = [book.author for book in books]
data = authors + list(books.all())
serialized_data = django.core.serializers.serialize("json", data)
```

My problem is that the remote application cannot deserialize without having a local database.

Comment: Why do you need models without database? This doesn't make any sense. Just create REST API, so that the server will make queries for remote application. And why can't you just copy files to remote app? Ever heard of repositories?

Comment: Does the remote computer know the structure of the models? If so you can just serialize the *fields etc in model and pass those over.

Comment: Remote application knows the models structure

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that you need to transfer models over http.
need just to connect to server db.
In remote app settings choose db engine (mysql in your case), name.
Specify appropriate user and password.
And enter a valid host and proxy (if needed). the one your database server is running on

As for the user. on the server create a mysql user with read only rights to the db.

This will give you the ability to use the same db for both, server and remote app.

Comment: The only access that the application can have to server (due to policy issues), is over http. In fact I want to set the values for the models on server and remote application should be able to read them (not all, but filtered) and perform certain actions according to model values. I need something like an http proxy for the models

Comment: Permit me to redirect you to a REST API lib. In case of Django project I can recommend you this one: http://django-rest-framework.org/
There are several other libs, but I have experience only with the one I mentioned and I liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved by using sqlite running on ram on client side

On settings.py I used this configuration

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:'
    }
}
```

And the code is like this:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from django.core import serializers
from apps.my_models import Book, Person

connection = connections['default']
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(Book, no_style(), set())
cursor.execute(sql[0])
sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(Person, no_style(), set())
cursor.execute(sql[0])

serialized_data = get_serialized_data()
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", serialized_data):
    obj.save()
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('author').all()
```

Comment: How does this connect to the remote server?